# How can I use ConstraintValidator directly?

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

I have an unusual use case.

In my left hand, I have a `String` value (say, "`5001`").  In my right hand I have an `Annotation` literal with some interesting information.  It basically defines a named "slot" for which (in this example) "`5001`" is an appropriate value.

Let us now also say that I have some `javax.validation.constraints` `Annotation` (like `Digits`) in my...other hand.  **Note that I do not have any reference to any field or method or any other `AnnotatedElement`—just the `javax.validation.constraints` `Annotation` literal itself.**  This is the weird part, but take it as fact.

Armed with these bits, I can *almost* use [`ConstraintValidator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html) to see if "`5001`" is a valid value for the "slot" defined by my annotation literal.  But not quite, as I cannot acquire a [`ConstraintValidatorContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.html) for use in the [`isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html#isValid-T-javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext-) method.

(I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409763/how-to-obtain-constraintvalidatorcontext) on the subject, which suggests that I'm out of luck.)

I also cannot simply use the `Validator` API as I am not validating a bean instance but instead merely a value that, if everything goes well, *may* be used indirectly in an XSLT file, if you must know.  :-)  It's the determining if everything is going to go well part that I'd like to use `javax.validation` for here.  But, as mentioned, I don't have a bean instance with an annotated element to validate—I just have the value that *would* go into that annotated element.

Is there a way forward here?

Comment: I think this is basically just a duplicate of question you are referring to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409763/how-to-obtain-constraintvalidatorcontext. There is no good solution for this using Bean Validation. Yes you could use the ConstraintValidator instances and yes for your use case you could even pass null as context instance, but this not not really just a hack. The default constraints make no use of the context, but things might break for custom constraints. Also you would be instantiating internal HV classes which is discouraged.

Comment: How many hands do you actually have :)

Comment: Is it just that you have no bean *instance* to which validation would be applied, or is there no bean *type* which would contain annotated fields/properties at all? In case of the former, `Validator#validateValue()` might be helpful, but I suppose that's not the case here.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. As I said, it's an odd use case. What I really have is a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`, housed in a bean, and a way of getting annotation literals that correspond with each entry in the sub-map. (I hate `Map`s of `Map`s, but have no choice here). So I'm going to try to write a very large hairy `ConstraintValidator` for the outermost `Map` and try validating the property that houses it. Here goes nothing.